# Python, NLTK: NameError: name 'load_parser' is not defined

Tags: python, parsing, nlp, nltk, nltk-book

I'm trying to run this example provided from NLTK book [here](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch10.html):

```
>>> from nltk import load_parser
>>> cp = load_parser('grammars/book_grammars/sql0.fcfg')
>>> query = 'What cities are located in China'
>>> trees = list(cp.parse(query.split()))
>>> answer = trees[0].label()['SEM']
>>> answer = [s for s in answer if s]
>>> q = ' '.join(answer)
>>> print(q)
SELECT City FROM city_table WHERE Country="china"
```

but when I type the first line it gives me this error:

```
NameError: name 'load_parser' is not defined
```

I tried looking for similar questions but none have the same issue. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

There are quite some namespace changes since the book release. `load_parser` now resides in [`nltk.parse.util`](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.parse.html?highlight=load_parser#nltk.parse.util.load_parser) and is imported at [`nltk.parse`](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/parse/__init__.py#L69).

In the latest version of NLTK, `from nltk import load_parser` should work:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.__version__
'3.2.3'
>>> from nltk import load_parser
```

Maybe in some NLTK versions, the namespace might not be correct. Or maybe somehow you've polluted your namespace earlier on. If a `NameError` occurs, then import the function from where the actual function is located:

```
from nltk.parse import load_parser
```

E.g.

```
>>> from nltk.parse import load_parser
>>> cp = load_parser('grammars/book_grammars/sql0.fcfg')
>>> query = 'What cities are located in China'
>>> trees = list(cp.parse(query.split()))
>>> answer = trees[0].label()['SEM']
>>> answer = [s for s in answer if s]
>>> q = ' '.join(answer)
>>> print q
SELECT City FROM city_table WHERE Country="china"
```

Comment: i've provided a link to the actual `load_parser` documentation rather than the github source code.

Answer (score 0):

I removed all nltk_data files and downloaded them again and it worked.